# Export Map Canvas QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, export, geopdf

I am trying to export a map canvas in QGIS I've made composed of .SHP files to a GeoTIFF, GeoPDF or any other georeferenced image.

All I want to be able to do is set a desired output resolution. I am unable to find anything on how do this. I keep getting pointed towards the Print Composer but that is for paper maps (DPI, etc.).

Where can I find this simple feature?

Comment: You can set size in print composer, look around other posts. Or try File -> Save as image.

Comment: In QGIS 2.x you have to use the print composer if you want to change the resolution of the image - see comment above from Mat. In QGIS 3.x you can exort the map with the desired resolution without using the composer.

Comment: The print composer is NOT just for paper maps. It's for creating many types of export, from paper maps to PDFs to JPGs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GRASS module, v.to.rast.value. Here it allows you to select the vector input layer, raster resolution and raster extents. For converting to GeoTIFF etc, I would suggest using Conversion in the gdal_plugin under your Raster menu.