# QGIS capture screenshot of visible map (PyQGIS or other alternatives)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I would like to take a screenshot of my QGIS area, which I am working on.

It does look pretty much as you can see below:

[image]

I would like to grab only the visible area of my map. I am not talking about map canvas, as mentioned here:

[Save map canvas as image with Python in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206838/save-map-canvas-as-image-with-python-in-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[PyQGIS make screenshot of mapCanvas after setExtent is called](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231446/pyqgis-make-screenshot-of-mapcanvas-after-setextent-is-called)

or here

[Saving Map Canvas as PNG with transparent background programmatically with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135768/saving-map-canvas-as-png-with-transparent-background-programmatically-with-qgis)

or here

[Export Map Canvas QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277527/export-map-canvas-qgis)

I simply want to have an option to grab the screen from my QGIS working area defined by it visible bounds (after dock windows visible).

I tried some of the codes, but they didn't work:

```
 mainPath = 'C:\\Users\\mk\\Desktop\\AX\\Pre survey\\Tyton\\'
 filename = 'StrandAAA'
 imageType = "png"

 imageWidth_mm = 400
 imageHeight_mm = 160
 dpi = 300

 mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()

 c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
 c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)

 c.setPaperSize(400, 160)

 x, y = 0, 0
 w, h = c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()
 composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x ,y, w, h)
 c.addItem(composerMap)

 # get all items and disable the backgrounds
 itemList = c.items()
 c.removeItem(itemList[2])
 c.removeItem(itemList[2])
 itemList[2].setBackgroundEnabled(False)
 itemList[3].setBackgroundEnabled(False)
 # add them to the composition
 c.addItem(itemList[2])
 c.addItem(itemList[3])

 c.refreshItems()
 c.refreshDataDefinedProperty(QgsComposerObject.AllProperties)

 c.setPrintResolution(dpi)
 dpmm = dpi / 25.4
 width = int(dpmm * c.paperWidth())
 height = int(dpmm * c.paperHeight())

 # create output image and initialize it
 # image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
 image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
 image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
 image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
 #image.fill(0)

 imagePainter = QPainter(image)

 # This part does not seem to have any effect
 #brush = QBrush(Qt.BrushStyle(0)) # transparent brush
 #
 #imagePainter.setBackgroundMode(0)
 #c.setBackgroundBrush(brush)

 c.renderPage( imagePainter, 0 )
 imagePainter.end()


 imageFilename =  mainPath + filename + '.' + imageType
 image.save(imageFilename, imageType)
 print 'image saved'
 print 'done
```

but it didn't work, the same as:

```
  vlayer.select(ID)
 qgis.utils.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
 vlayer.deselect(ID)
 qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage('C:\\Users\\mk\\Desktop\\AX\\Pre survey\\Tyton\\feature.png')
```

The solution is shown on the YT channel here also wasn't successful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17AXqO5_s7g&ab_channel=OpenSourceOptions

I think I am closer to this solution:

[Is it possible to take automatically a "screenshot" of my selected feature in QGIS using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31972/is-it-possible-to-take-automatically-a-screenshot-of-my-selected-feature-in-qg)

butt instead of selected feature I need the visible map area

The typical solution for taking a screenshot in Windows doesn't solve my request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python

although in Pyscreenshot v2.3 I can define the rough bounds of my screen and capture them, how about if I change my QGIS window to another place

https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/#files

Is there an option to capture the screenshot of the visible map in QGIS both by using PyGIS or maybe not programmatically (GRASS or sth?)

Comment: what was wrong with `iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage()`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsMapCanvas' object has no attribute 'mapRenderer'

Comment: an answer is on this page? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291545/exporting-map-canvas-to-png-file-using-custom-plugin-created-by-plugin-builder

Comment: Yes, it's a good one! Thanks! The only one smallish thing that is irritating. Why along with my .png files I am getting the .pgw extension too?

Comment: @Mapperz don't worry about it. I solved it by using the simply python script available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834731/how-to-delete-a-file-by-extension-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following to capture the QGIS main window area with all infos if you use "pyscreenshot"

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QScreen
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')
mainWin = iface.mainWindow()

x, y, w, h = mainWin.x(), mainWin.y(), mainWin.width(), mainWin.height()
bbox = (x, y, x + w, y + h)
# part of the screen
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bbox)

# save image file
im.save(f"/tmp/{filename}.png")

# If you want a dialog box (above im.save can be commented in this case)
path, ok = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(mainWin, "Save file", "", "Images (*.png *.jpg)");
if ok:
    im.save(path)
```

If you want only the map area, it should be

```
# Change the path
iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage('/tmp/out.png')

# You can also use the following to reuse existing dialog for saving image
iface.actionSaveMapAsImage().trigger()
```

Comment: That's perfect! How can I add the "Save As" window pop-up?

Is it:
 file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
    myScreenshot.save(file_path)?

Comment: Edited answer for this intent

Comment: I am getting an error like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.12/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 743, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyscreenshot'

Comment: I used the second one frankly and it works well:

iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(mainWin, "Save file", "", "Images (*.png *.jpg)"))

what I am missing is the DPI resolution for my image.

Comment: For the first error, it's because you did not instal `pyscreenshot` module within the PyQGIS Python version

Comment: Updated 2nd answer to use existing method to save a image (same as existing one when you go through the menu)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It's perfect. The last thing is the DPI. Is there an option to change it? It seems to be fixed.

Comment: With `iface.actionSaveMapAsImage().trigger()` in my update answer, you can choose

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I have to choose it every time. It's troublesome as I have 208 records to proceed. I tried now with something like:
iface.actionSaveMapAsImage().trigger().setDpi(250) but it didn't work

Comment: Not implemented at the moment... https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/13975

Comment: That's a pity. Thank you very much for your contribution here.