# PyQGIS autoexport map canvas to PNG file with choosing location option

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Following the query here:

[QGIS capture screenshot of visible map (PyQGIS or other alternatives)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392645/qgis-capture-screenshot-of-visible-map-pyqgis-or-other-alternatives?noredirect=1#comment642551_392645)

I would like to have the Export PDF option confined to clicking the button on my keyboard.

By using the solutions available here:

https://datatofish.com/screenshot-python/

I tried to do something like this with my code:

```
 import keyboard

 # if keyboard.is_pressed('Alt+S'):  (optionally, although I can still use the Run function in my Python console)

 file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
 iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(file_path)
```

But I am getting errors i.e.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in
> runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 5
> file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
> ^

IndentationError: expected an indented block**

How can I save my screenshot with choosing and file name option?

I used another approach:

```
    iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(mainWin, "Save 
    file", "", "PNG Format (*.png)"))
```

but I am getting an error here:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in
> runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 1, in  TypeError:
> QgsMapCanvas.saveAsImage(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'

Answer (score 0):

If line 90 follows an **if** statement,  it must be indented in Python.