Save images of raster layer based on polygon - QGIS
i have a background raster layer and a vector layer with different polygons.
Is it possible to save "images" from the raster layer that are within each polygon?
I have 100 polygons and would like to only save images of the raster layer from within each polygon.
Is this possible using QGIS?


You didn't add your image, please edit your question accordingly.

Hi Erik, thank you for letting me know. I have now added the picture

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392645/qgis-capture-screenshot-of-visible-map-pyqgis-or-other-alternatives - there are some python based solutions. I am not proficient enough to know, which parts of the code you need to adapt.

Yes, you can. Find Clip raster by mask layer tool in the Processing toolbox: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#gdalcliprasterbymasklayer

You raster is file based, not a WMS layer?

@ComradeChe Thank you! Do you know if i can use this option with "Google sat"?

@BERA It is a WMS layer, i am using this URL: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

That is an XYZ layer not a WMS layer.

if all you need is an image then the atlas print functionality would work for you

@IanTurton And i can use this method to get the highest possible resolution images from my xyz layer that are within each of my polygones (I have more than 1000)?
Thank you for helping

First turn off your polygons and zoom into the area you want to clip.
then use the "Convert map to Raster" tool from the processing toolbox.
Turn your polygons back on and use the "Clip raster by mask" tool as @Comrade Che suggested.
That should get you close.



Thank you a lot for your help! :D

Did the above answer work?  If so please mark it as the solution.
